# How to prevent my site to crash when adding video content using the Media Colorbox module?

Tags: 7, media, javascript

I'm having a lot of issues when trying to set up my [Media Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_colorbox) module.

For images, the Colorbox module works just fabulous, but whenever I try to add some video content in this Colorbox overlay, the site just crashes: I get a white screen, and the site just keeps loading. It's like it's looking for a file, but it cannot find it, although the link is correct because the file is actually there. The permissions for the files are correctly set.

I've tried many setups, tips and tricks documented on the Drupal pages, with no luck. What I want to achieve is perfectly demonstrated on [this page](http://kendragrittani.com/video), and although my code looks exactly the same, my content just wouldn't load.

I'm using the most recent versions of all modules:

- [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox): 7.x-2.2
- Media Colorbox: 7.x-1.0-rc3
- [File Entity (fieldable files)](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) 7.x-2.0-unstable7

I don't think there is an issue with that.

I've tried any possible CSS class: colorbox-inline, colorbox-load, and colorbox-video. I cannot access those movies by surfing to them, although the path is correct.

Comment: I have moved the relevant information in the question, and deleted the comments.

Comment: Are you trying to load a video file that you have hosted (mp4, avi, etc) or are you trying to load a YouTube video through a URL?

I made [this](https://www.kimbellart.org/interact) using Views Slideshow, Colorbox (colorbox-load), and a bit of tweaking. Just make sure your colorbox-load setting is turned on in the config.

Comment: I'm trying to load videos I host on my own server, but they don't even load...

Comment: @Michiel It's possible the video is too big for the hosting services you have. Try to load YouTube and/or different video format to see what happen.

Answer (score 1):

Might there be an incorrect link to a video player library or something? Maybe it's the setup of the player and not colorbox, media colorbox, or file entity. Just guessing....

Answer (score 1):

Your issues may also have to do with Colorbox not playing well with inline images in Drupal 7. One way of getting around this is using the Insert module to place content in the body field of your node, or to create an image field that can be used to display Colorbox images.